# Sending progress updates from the FastAPI Backend server to the Client

Tags: python, backend, fastapi

- I have implemented two APIs, one to upload video and the other to process video.
- After video is uploaded the process video starts from within the upload video API.
- The processing happens within a Docker container and to get the progress updates from the Docker container
- I have used a thread to fetch it from progress.txt which is inside the docker container.
- The progress.txt updates every 30 seconds until the processing is over. Currently the code prints the progress at the server side in the terminal.

I want to send this progress to the client side in real time and I'm new to Backend. The FrontEnd is currently not ready would love to test it with client side created in python itself. How to implement it without hindering the process video?

The below is upload_video API

```
@app.post("/api/upload_video")
async def upload_video(video: UploadFile = File(...)):
    try:
        # Check if the file has a valid video extension
        print("Received Request to upload video")
        if not is_valid_video_extension(video.filename):
            raise HTTPException(status_code=400, detail="Invalid video file extension. Supported extensions: mp4, avi, mkv, MOV")

        video_path = os.path.join(local_folder, video.filename)
        with open(video_path, 'wb') as video_file:
            video_file.write(video.file.read())
        
        print("Video Uploading completed")
        # Call process_video function after upload
        path=os.path.join(video_folder_docker,video.filename)
        video_request = VideoRequest(file_path=path)
        result = await process_video(video_request)
        print("Video Processing completed")
        return result  # Return the processed result directly
    except Exception as e:
        error_message = str(e)
        print(f"Error in upload_video: {error_message}")
        raise HTTPException(status_code=500, detail=f"Internal Server Error: {error_message}")
```

The below is process_video API with progress funtion

```
progress_exit_event = Event()
@app.post("/api/process_video")
async def process_video(video_request: VideoRequest):
    try:
        
        print("Received request for video processing")
        
        env_commands = [
            'export PATH=/demo/bins/:$PATH'
        ]
        execution_command = f'{container_script_path} {video_request.file_path}' 
        command = f"{' && '.join(env_commands)} && {execution_command}"
        
        client = docker.from_env()
        
        try:
            container = client.containers.get(container_name)
        except docker.errors.NotFound:
            raise HTTPException(status_code=status.HTTP_404_NOT_FOUND, detail=f"Docker container '{container_name}' not found.")
        
        # Start a separate thread to print progress
        progress_thread = threading.Thread(target=print_progress, args=(container, progress_exit_event))
        progress_thread.start()
        
        result = container.exec_run(['/bin/bash', '-c', command])
        
        progress_exit_event.set()
        
        progress_thread.join()
        
        if result.exit_code != 0:
            error_message = result.output.decode('utf-8')
            print(f"Error executing command in Docker container: {error_message}")
            raise HTTPException(status_code=status.HTTP_500_INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR, detail=f"Internal Server Error: {error_message}")
        
        json_file1_path = os.path.join(container_script_path[:-18], 'sync_events.json')
        json_file2_path = os.path.join(container_script_path[:-18], 'summary.json')
        
        if not file_exists_in_container(container, json_file1_path) or not file_exists_in_container(container, json_file2_path):
            raise HTTPException(status_code=status.HTTP_500_INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR, detail="JSON files not found in the specified paths.")
        
        json_file1_content = container.exec_run(['/bin/cat', json_file1_path]).output
        json_file2_content = container.exec_run(['/bin/cat', json_file2_path]).output
        
        json_content1 = json.loads(json_file1_content.decode('utf-8'))
        json_content2 = json.loads(json_file2_content.decode('utf-8'))

        print(100,"%")
        
        return {"sync_events": json_content1, "summary": json_content2}
    
    except Exception as e:
        error_message = str(e)
        print(f"Error in process_video: {error_message}")
        raise HTTPException(status_code=status.HTTP_500_INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR, detail=f"Internal Server Error: {error_message}")

def print_progress(container, exit_event):
    try:
        progress_file_path = '/demo/build/progress.txt'
        pc=-2
        # while True:
        while not exit_event.is_set():
            # Read and print the contents of progress.txt
            progress_content = container.exec_run(['/bin/cat', progress_file_path]).output.decode('utf-8')
            progress_integer = int(progress_content)
            if progress_integer==-1:
                continue
            if pc==progress_integer:
                continue
            print(progress_integer,"%") 
            pc=progress_integer

    except Exception as e:
        print(f"Error in print_progress: {str(e)}")
```

Comment: Never trust `video.filename` in any way. Create your own, local filename - do _not_ use the filename given by a user to do any kind of validation or as part of your path when writing it - the filename can be `../../bar` etc. to attempt to write to any random file on your server/inside your container. Generate a safe id and use that. For progress report you can poll an endpoint that uses the id and reads the progress file for that container, or instead of polling you can use for example a websocket or server sent events.

Comment: don't use `async def` for endpoints with blocking code

Comment: @MatsLindh Thanks for the advice. Can you recommend me some materials or blogs on how to do polling? 
I tried using websocket (my implementation could be wrong) but server did connect to the client but it didn't send the progress to the client and after sometime the connection closed in the client side. In most cases of the blogs the websocket_endpoint is directly the one starting processes, but in my case process_video API starts it, so not sure how to proceed

Comment: I don't have any resources, but you could for example return a uuid from your upload function, queue the video for processing, and then publish updates for that uuid to a redis pubsub-queue or similar. The websocket would subscribe to messages from that queue, and then republish them to the client as they appear.

Comment: Okay thank you for the suggestions, I have implemented websocket for the above